# Better indicate there is a link in my careers profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've placed a couple links to media sources on my careers profile to provide more context of my previous positions. When I attach a resume to an application, I have the option of generating a PDF.

This PDF has two options - Show link URLs or don't show them.

If I select to show the URLs, it italicizes the text I have the markdown link wrapped around and then shows the full URL. If I don't show the URL (because some of them are long and ugly), the only indication that there is a link present is if you happen to run your mouse over the text and see it changes to a hand cursor.

I want to keep the PDF "pretty" (without showing long, ugly URL strings), but I also want to provide some indication that there is more data available because there is a link here.

Would it be possible to keep the italics or include a thin dashed underline on text that is a link? This will show that there is something available that provides more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.  Agreed, links should be obvious. We'll have someone look into this. In the meantime, I've set the status to deferred.

Comment: This update has been implemented and is live now. Thanks!